# Combining Django Templates and Polymer

Tags: django, django-templates, polymer

I've been stuck for the past few hours trying to figure out why the core Polymer elements are not being displayed properly in a Django application I'm making to act as a personal webpage. The [application](https://bitbucket.org/amcmanus/polymer-django/src) at the moment just points to an index.html page which, if you follow the [tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/) on Polymer, is up to step one.

However, the components are not loading on my page. The static files are all set up correctly, and there's subtle animation from the css files being loaded correctly, but the Roboto font and the core-elements are not being displayed. Running the site as a normal HTML file does everything correctly.

Is there a specific way to user Polymer in a Django template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See Eric's answer to this on the polymer-dev mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/polymer-dev/django/polymer-dev/N2R8qknalOI/58ZhC1gWFh4J

*Relevant excerpt:*

Django 1.5 has support for the verbatim tag. You can wrap your inlined element definitions in that:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim

*Example code snippet:*

```
{% verbatim %}
<template repeat="{{item as items}}">
  <my-element name="{{item.name}}"></my-element>
</template>
{% endverbatim %}

<script>
  document.querySelector("template').model = {{items}}; // items here is filled by the server's template.
</script>
```

Comment: This works. What also helps is setting the CSS correctly for the page. Complete mistake on my part, but good to confirm Verbatim is required.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the fact that Django uses the same `{{}}` in its templates as Polymer.

Comment: You'll probably have to serve your components up separately so Django doesn't replace all the Polymer elements' `{{}}`. That's what [this](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/13/web-components.html) seems to recommend.

Comment: I don't know Django, but there might also be a way to tell Django not to parse any `.html` files in your `components` directory.

Comment: I've gotten around this in the past by using an `include_raw` tag. This tells Django not to interpret that section of code https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-dashboard/blob/master/customtags/templatetags/include_raw.py

Comment: It does seem to be the template loader rendering '{{ }}' making the elements fail. However, trying to manually wrap '{% verbatim %}' tags around the instances of '{{ }}' in the files polymer is calling doesn't display the content correctly. It also isn't handy that the elements call other html files which have more '{{ }}' in them.

@ebidel - How do you implement this template tag when calling the files from static content? Looks like a way to go, but unsure how to  use this tag.

Comment: If the files are truly static, they don't be processed by djnago's templating engine. Shouldn't be an issue. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your setup.

Comment: @ebidel All the Polymer elements are currently in staticfiles and being called like <link rel="import" href="{% static 'component/component.html' %}". There's a few instances of data-binding in the element templates which I think are not causing it to render properly, but I'll have another look at it tonight to see if I've done anything in particular wrong.

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part - I neglected the CSS that is required from the example - none of it generates without it. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer as a compliment to the already accepted answer.

You can force django to require a space for it's template tags. So for any django template tags you have to use `{{ variable }}` and for polymer you will use `{{variable}}`.

Here is a very simple module/app I created to "prepare" django for use alongside polymer.

[https://github.com/andrewebdev/django-ostinato/blob/2c435dea23319be6e9011e7381afca2b4092b5a2/ostinato/polyprep/**init**.py](https://github.com/andrewebdev/django-ostinato/blob/2c435dea23319be6e9011e7381afca2b4092b5a2/ostinato/polyprep/__init__.py)

Credit goes to https://github.com/nebrybledu for this suggestion.